# Find value in selected column

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I want to find a value in a particular column.

In Excel, I would select the column and press `Ctrl + f`.  The same procedure in Libreoffice-Calc searches the entire spreadsheet.  There doesn't seem to be any option to limit the search to within the region.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Find & Replace Box by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, under the collapsible "`Other options`," there should be a checkbox for "`Current selection only`."